# Contents are all selected by default

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

[image]First, I don't know what happed, which means the cause may not as the title suggests.

I was editing with vim.  one or two mis-key strokes, now whenever I open file with vim. All the Contents are all selected by default (please see screenshot once the file open up, it is all yellow highlight?, once I select the context "using namespacre std to (line) defines poin, then it look normal again. ). When I select the contents. it look normal again. How can i fix it ? I quit and re-open didn't work. i even empty the vimrc and source the it. didn't work as well. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing the `vimrc`, you could try removing `~/.viminfo`.

If the problem persists, try disabling your plugins - alternatively you could start Vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N`, which disables both initialization files and plugins, as explained in [this similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file).

As a last resort, try installing the latest Vim version.